# Why not just one unified `scale_fill` function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colormap

Can someone explain to me why `scale_fill_discrete` and `scale_fill_continuous` need to be different functions? (and likewise `scale_color_*`) I understand that some colormaps are only defined for discrete data, but for reusable plotting functions, I am constantly writing silly logic to check whether the fill (or color) variable is discrete to call the right `scale_fill_*` function. Same for `scale_fill_distiller` and `scale_fill_brewer`.

Why can we not merge these functions and just throw an error if a discrete colormap option is requested for continuous data?  This is already being checked internally to throw errors in the current functions.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons.

First, the defaults for the two functions are different.  `scale_fill_discrete` will default to `type = scale_fill_hue`, i.e.
evenly spaced colours around the colour wheel.  `scale_fill_continuous` will default to `type = scale_fill_gradient`, evenly spaced colours between two extremes.  (There's also a third function, `scale_fill_binned`, which belongs in the same family.  It has different defaults too.)

The second reason is style.  If you don't like the defaults, you can define your own through options.  But it wouldn't make sense for discrete and continuous colour sets to be the same, so you'd need to specify two defaults.  (They are named `"ggplot2.discrete.fill"` and `"ggplot2.continuous.fill"`).  It's a cleaner style to also have two functions to use these options, rather than a single more complicated function that chooses between them.  At least in the opinion of the authors of `ggplot2`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still think it would be simple enough to switch between the defaults based on whether the variable is continuous or discrete. You don't even have to change the implementation of custom options -- again, just select one based on the variable type. I hear you about clean style but clean package code currently translates to messy user code, so, which is worse...?

Comment: I think the assumption is that the user usually knows what kind of data they're working with.  If that's not the case with the data you have, you should probably write a single `scale_fill_auto` function that makes the choice you want, and use that:  clean code in `ggplot2` and in your scripts.  Of course, that might not be an easy function to write, given the way `ggplot2` works.

Comment: ... and if it's hard to write `scale_fill_auto`, that's a 3rd reason.

Comment: That's essentially what I've done. It's not so bad, but I'm also trying to integrate colormaps from several external packages too, and they each have their own arguments & ways of dealing with discrete vs continuous variables.